# Activiti6 use spring-boot-starter-web meet requestMappingHandlerMapping error

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

Update:
Some people found add (`exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class`) can skip this ‍`error` :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ActivitiApplication { ... }
```

---

I am using activiti and spring-boot,
and when i mix activiti with spring-boot-starter-basic it is ok.
But when i add spring-boot-starter-web in my `pom.xml`,
i meet the following `error` :

Here is my `codes` :

https://github.com/cybfly/activiti-demo

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.ActivitiApplication.main(ActivitiApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:573) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.isHandler(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:217) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:188) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:129) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Try excluding the Activiti SecurityAutoConfiguration class.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you are using a version of Activiti Spring Boot integration for Spring Boot 1.5.x not Spring boot 2.x

Comment: Thanks. i asked in the spring-boot github, and wilkinsona told me spring-boot 2.0 is not compatible with activiti 6.0.0. I think it might be the reason you mentioned. Cause activiti 6 released early than spring-boot 2. I will try to overwrite the starter-web version to 1.5.x in pom.xml to see if things can work around.

Comment: We are working on activiti 7 to work on top of spring boot 2 and spring cloud. What kind of use case are you trying to implement?

Comment: In fact my case is quite simple, i just try to learn the basic use of activiti with spring-boot, in this case i just find it impossible to use rest-api with spring-boot 2. And it seems the structure of activiti 7 is different with the early version. So i think maybe i can use activiti 6 first.

Comment: And the version of activiti make me confused. Because when i learn the history of activit. I find the main coder for this project fork activiti 5.21 and release flowable 5.22 in 2016.

Comment: I totally understand the confusion, that usually happens with people fork open source projects. Activiti Cloud (7) is focused on Cloud Deployments using Spring Boot 2 and Spring Cloud Finchley as base frameworks. That's why you notice changes in structure. We are currently focused in following a Continuous Deployment and Microservices approach for each of our open source modules. We hope to release Beta1 version soon to Maven Central.