# How to properly set activiti framework for Spring-boot2

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti

Question updated following remarks under this question.

When I'm trying to run spring-boot2 project together with Activiti framework, I'm receiving issues described little bit lower.

First of all, this project was created with Spring Initializer, all further development was done using this tutorial - [How to start Activiti + Spring JPA with Spring Boot](http://javasampleapproach.com/java-integration/start-activiti-spring-jpa-spring-boot).

This tutorial describes how to use it together with Spring-boot 1.x. And with this condition (spring-boot-1.x and activiti dependencies with version from tutorial), it was working fine. However, I need this for **Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE** as in this type of Project I will finally implement it, and here was only a training case.

I found on few websites information, that with spring-boot2 proper version of activiti should v7, but I'm not able to make it working. I did some steps regarding the dependencies in pom.xml (play a bit with versions) but none of them worked. So as per request, I'm attaching also current pom.xml as well as link to the github repo - https://github.com/mjuTutorials/activiti-basic-demo

Can anyone please let me know how to set pom.xml correctly and also, is there anything more required in the code in order to make it working?

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.threem</groupId>
    <artifactId>car-rental-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>car-rental-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springfox-swagger2.version>2.6.0</springfox-swagger2.version>  <!-- Swagger -->
        <querydsl.version>4.1.3</querydsl.version>
        <mockito.core.version>2.18.3</mockito.core.version>
        <junitparams.version>1.1.1</junitparams.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
            <version>${junitparams.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
               </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

Attached error log:

**com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplicationTests.txt**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.966 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

**TEST-com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplicationTests.xml**

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-03 22:03:00.142 ERROR 876 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:646) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.lambda$processDeferredImportSelectors$2(ConfigurationClassParser.java:566) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:563) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139) [spring-boot-test-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:732) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:948) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:333) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:194) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:636) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 43 common frames omitted

2018-07-03 22:03:00.144 ERROR 876 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@26275bef] to prepare test instance [com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplicationTests@77774571]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.mjuapps.actividemo.ActiviDemoApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:646) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.lambda$processDeferredImportSelectors$2(ConfigurationClassParser.java:566) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:563) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at ....
```

Comment: Downvote reason: Please specify the question as it is currently just a title, and it should be conveying the essence of your issue. Please also share specifics: How is the project set up? What exact steps have you tried? Do your team member see the same issue on their system? etc.

Comment: update your question by showing your pom.xml

Comment: Updated following request

Comment: We're also trying to use activity 6 with spring-boot 2.0.1 with no success. Apparently they are not compatible, as stated in [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-activiti) from 31st of March: "It works with Spring Boot up through v1.5.4. It doesn’t work with v2.0.0.M1 yet."

Interestingly, we managed to get it working with Activiti 5, but introducing an outdated technology in a brand-new app is not a good idea. They promised support for spring-boot 2 in Activiti 7, but that is not released yet, so we're currently looking at alternatives (camunda).

Answer (score 0):

i followed others experience and already setup Activiti6 + spring-boot 2.0.

Just like the question i asked below:

[Activiti6 use spring-boot-starter-web meet requestMappingHandlerMapping error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097584/activiti6-use-spring-boot-starter-web-meet-requestmappinghandlermapping-error)

Remember to add exclude in the SpringBootApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Here is the demo and you can try to build your owner project upon it：

https://github.com/cybfly/activiti-demo

The pom.xml like this:

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <activiti.version>6.0.0</activiti.version>
</properties>
```